# Android + AdMob problem

Tags: android, admob

I have a problem with AdView. When I start activity with this view and it looks like something goes in eternal loop and I see a lot of log appearence:

```
02-01 21:57:34.437: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.512: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.512: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.587: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.587: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.657: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.657: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.727: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.727: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.797: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.802: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.872: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:34.887: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:35.002: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:35.092: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:35.092: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:35.172: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:35.172: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:35.267: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:35.267: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
02-01 21:57:35.527: WARN/AdMobSDK(29740): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
```

Many many many times

Here is may layout for this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:sac="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.myapp"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/bFlashLight"
            android:lines="1" android:ellipsize="end" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000" android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/mapview"
            android:text="@string/open_flashlight" />

    <ZoomControls android:id="@+id/zoomcontrols"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bFlashLight" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/mapview" />

    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                  sac:backgroundColor="#000000" sac:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
                                  sac:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to disable auto invoke of requestFreshAd() method?

Comment: Are you manually calling the ad in code or are you only using the xml? Also, what does the outside layout look like, are they all party of a linear layout?

Comment: no direct code calls for adds, only xml. The root container is RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resovied by update of library

Answer (score 3):

just choose separate linear layout  add this code and refresh time mention in admob site or u r code file  its working

```
<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.myapp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </com.admob.android.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```